# regex to restrict last 8 digits not to be repeated

Tags: regex

I need a regex to restrict repetition of number on a mobile phone not more than 7 times.
Initial digit has to be a `0`, second digit can be `2`, `3`, `4`, `7` or `8`.
The last 8 digits are not to be repeated (They should not be the same number).
I have the following regex which checks for spaces as well and makes sure the rest of the digits are numbers from `0-9` only:

```
[\\s]*[0][\\s]*[23478][0-9\\s]*
```

I need help to restrict last 8 digits not to be repeated (they should not be same).

suppose if I enter "0422222222"

i need to restrict the last 8 digits not being the same.
0 - in the first place
2,3,4,7,8 - in the second place
Places 3 - 10  i.e. last eight digits - not to be the same number.
They can be any numbers between 0-9, they can repeat upto 7 times out of the available 8 places from 3 to 10.
They cannot repeat 8 times. That is not all 8 digits from 3 -10 places should be taken up by a single number. I hope I am clear this time. waiting for your response.

Comment: there's number 1 ? what is the max length

Comment: Please fix the formatting in your question. Use [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for the regex.

Comment: `last 8 digits are not to be repeated` Do you mean they cannot be repeated anywhere? Or just that you cannot have `33`, but `343` is okay?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: This would almost be easier with a little code instead of a regex.

Comment: "not to be the same number" is still totally ambiguous. Do you mean they all need to be different? No two consecutive numbers can be the same? Or they just can't ALL be the same single digit???

Comment: suppose if i enter "0422222222"

i need to restrict the last 8 digits not being the same. 0 - in the first place 2,3,4,7,8 - in the second place Places 3 - 10 i.e. last eight digits - not to be the same number.

Comment: I am using JavaScript language and trying to provide a regex in a JQuery

Comment: Or they just can't ALL be the same single digit??? - yes

Comment: last eight places are not to be filled by the same number consecutively..

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that a digit can not be immediately followed by the same digit, you can use something like this:

```
^0[2-47-8](?:([0-9])(?!\1)){8}$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pT6vD4).

**Option 2: allowing spaces anywhere**

```
^0[ ]*[2-47-8][ ]*(?:[ ]*([0-9])(?![ ]*\1)){8}$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/bL3eF8). Note that there is no need for the brackets around the `[ ]` spaces, but it makes it easier to read.

**Option 3: only excluding one digit repeated 8 times**

```
^0[ ]*[2-47-8][ ]*(?:[ ]*([0-9])(?!(?:[ ]*\1){7}))(?:[ ]*[0-9]){7}$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yG9gB6).

**Explanation for Option 2**

- `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `0[ ]*` matches the zero and optional spaces
- `[2-47-8][ ]*` matches 2,3,4,7 or 8 and optional spaces
- `(?:[ ]*([0-9])` matches optional spaces `[ ]*`, then one digit `([0-9])` is matched and captured to Group 1
- the negative lookahead `(?!(?:[ ]*\1){7}))` asserts that what follows is not the same digit seven times (with optional spaces in between)
- `(?:[ ]*[0-9]){7}` matches the final seven digits
- `$` asserts that we have reached the end of the string

**Explanation for Option 3**

- `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `0[ ]*` matches the zero and optional spaces
- `[2-47-8][ ]*` matches 2,3,4,7 or 8 and optional spaces
- `(?:[ ]*([0-9])(?![ ]*\1))` matches optional spaces `[ ]*`, then one digit `([0-9])` is matched and captured to Group 1, as long as the negative lookahead `(?![ ]*\1)` is able to assert that what follows is not optional spaces and the same digit, as referred to by the back-reference `\1`
- and this is repeated 8 times by the `{8}` quantifier
- `$` asserts that we have reached the end of the string

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: +1, @zx81 Please add a link for more examples of Back-reference.

Comment: suppose if i enter "0422222222"

i need to restrict the last 8 digits not being the same. 0 - in the first place 2,3,4,7,8 - in the second place Places 3 - 10 i.e. last eight digits - not to be the same number.

Comment: Hey there, did you see the option I added? Is it working for you?

Comment: See that [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yG9gB6) Let me know, thanks. :)

Comment: What is not working? In the demo, is it matching something you don't want? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
^0[23478][\s\d]*\s*(\d)\s*(?!\1)(\d)\s*(?!\1|\2)(\d)\s*(?!\1|\2|\3)(\d)\s*(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)(\d)\s*(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5)(\d)\s*(?!.*\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)(\d)\s*(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7)(\d)$
```

[Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/tq4hP9SnDX)

This expression uses negative lookahead to restrict the next digit from being one of the previous ones. Explanation:

```
^                                 - start of line
0[23478]                          - 0 followed by '2' or '3' or '4' or '7' or '8'
[\s\d]*                           - digits or spaces before the last 8
                                    (if you only need leading two and last eight,
                                    i.e. total 10 digits, delete this bit)
\s*(\d)                           - first digit of eight
\s*(?!\1)(\d)                     - second digit of eight, different from first
\s*(?!\1|\2)(\d)                  - third digit of eight, different from first and second
etc.                              - etc
\s*(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7)(\d)   - last digit of eight, different from the first seven
$                                 - end of line
```

This works for Ruby regexp implementations, and will work for most other engines; but when you are asking about regexps, indicating which implementation you're using, since various things might not work (such as negative lookbehind `(?!...)`).

EDIT: Syntax brainfart. Thanks, ooga.

UPDATE after the clarification:

```
^0\s*[23478]\s*(\d)(?!(?:\s*\1){7})(?:\s*\d){7}$
```

Explanation:

```
^                 - start of line
0\s*[23478]       - '0' followed by '2' or '3' or '4' or '7' or '8'
                    (with optional spacing that I forgot the last time time)
\s*(\d)           - a digit (with optional spacing)
(?!(?:\s*\1){7})  - not followed by 7 of the same (with optional spacing)
(?:\s*\d){7}      - but followed nevertheless by 7 digits (with optional spacing)
$                 - end of line
```

Comment: This matches `0476438911345678`.

Comment: What I mean is that it seems to only ensure that the last 7 are relatively unique, not the last 8.

Comment: You are correct, I messed up my lookbehind syntax. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No prob. Great answer. Although the OP's spec is ambiguous, this is the most interesting interpretation.

Comment: suppose if i enter "0422222222"

i need to restrict the last 8 digits not being the same. 0 - in the first place 2,3,4,7,8 - in the second place Places 3 - 10 i.e. last eight digits - not to be the same number.

Comment: They can be any numbers between 0-9, they can repeat upto 7 times out of the available 8 places from 3 to 10.
They cannot repeat 8 times. That is not all 8 digits from 3 -10 places should be taken up by a single number. I hope I am clear this time. waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

your could use this pattern
`^0\s*[23478]\s*(\d)(?=.*(?!\s|\1|$))(?:\s*\d){7}$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pE7dJ3)

- `^0\s*[23478]\s*(\d)` the first portion, easy + capture 3rd digit
- `(?=.*(?!\s|\1|$))` look ahead for .* that does not see (\s or \1 "3rd digit" or $) ie another digit
- `(?:\s*\d){7}$` eat up the rest of the optional spaces and 7 digits.

Comment: suppose if i enter "0422222222" i need to restrict the last 8 digits not being the same. 0 - in the first place 2,3,4,7,8 - in the second place Places 3 - 10 i.e. last eight digits - not to be the same number.

Comment: They can be any numbers between 0-9, they can repeat upto 7 times out of the available 8 places from 3 to 10. They cannot repeat 8 times. That is not all 8 digits from 3 -10 places should be taken up by a single number. I hope I am clear this time. waiting for your response

Comment: you are clear just fine, example using the same pattern on "0422222222" works fine as well [here](http://regex101.com/r/nJ1zJ2)

Comment: i want to restrict this behaviour and not allow user to enter the same number for the last 8 places from 3 to 10

Comment: RegEx does not restrict repetition, it matches patterns. you would use it to verify the validity of the user entry and use your programming language to allow/restrict this behavior!

Comment: in this case it does not match the pattern. I have restricted the occurrence by writing an if condition.

Comment: did you see the example link I provided earlier? it matches what you want and skips what you don't want! here it is again [Example](http://regex101.com/r/nC1uF2)

Comment: Yes i tried to demo and use it in my code but it does not work

Comment: I used regex : ^0\s*[23478]\s*(\d)(?=.*(?!\s|\1|$))(?:\s*\d){7}$

Comment: It does not match 0422222222

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/pE7dJ3

Comment: it was matching valid entries, to match a non valid entry try [this](http://regex101.com/r/oR0cU2)